# Cambiar posición Tooltip (Bootstrap) al hacer scroll con Jquery

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy tratando de cambiar la posición de un Tooltip de Bootstrap al hacer scroll mediante Jquery. El atributo data-placement se cambia pero el efecto no funciona.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  var threshold = 20;
  if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 1)
    $('#faX').attr('data-placement', 'top');
  else
    $('#faX').attr('data-placement', 'bottom');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p style="margin:200px"></p>
<p><a class="iconsLogo" href="#"><i id="faX" class="fa fa fa-facebook fa2" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Seguinos en Facebook!" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
<p style="margin:200px"></p>
```

Comment: Correción: El id de i seria "faX"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se hace mediante las opciones del objeto tooltip:

```
$('#faX').data('bs.tooltip').option
```

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  var threshold = 20;
  if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 1)
   $('#faX').data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'bottom';
  else
    $('#faX').data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'top';
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p style="margin:200px"></p>
<p><a class="iconsLogo" href="#"><i id="faX" class="fa fa fa-facebook fa2" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Seguinos en Facebook!" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
<p style="margin:200px"></p>
```

Comment: Excelente! Muchas gracias!